# change icon color when add item to favorite database

Tags: java, android

When I click the heart icon it sends the item to favorite and color changes, 
but when loading the activity the icon back to normal 
color but the item still in the favorite.

How can i check if the item in the favorite or not to change the icon 
color based on that something like listener with database room ?

Here is the adapter :-

```
    public class BSAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BSAdapter.BestSellerHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private List<ProductsBestSeller> bestSellerList;


    public BSAdapter(Context context, List<ProductsBestSeller> bestSellerList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.bestSellerList = bestSellerList;
    }

    @Override
    public BestSellerHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View bestSellerView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.default_product_items_horizontal, parent, false);
        return new BestSellerHolder(bestSellerView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(BestSellerHolder holder, int position) {
        ProductsBestSeller bestSeller = bestSellerList.get(position);
        holder.onBindData(bestSeller);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (bestSellerList != null) {
            return bestSellerList.size();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public class BestSellerHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView productName, productPrice;
        ImageView productIcon;
        CheckBox favouriteIcon;


        public BestSellerHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            productIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_icon_horizontal);
            productName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_name_horizontal);
            productPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_price_horizontal);
            favouriteIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.favourite_icon_horizontal);
        }

        private void onBindData(ProductsBestSeller bestSeller) {
            if (Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().locale.getLanguage().equals(Locale.ENGLISH.toString())) {
                productName.setText(bestSeller.getNameEn());
            } else {
                productName.setText(bestSeller.getNameAr());
            }
            Glide.with(context).load(bestSeller.getImage()).into(productIcon);
            productPrice.setText(String.valueOf(bestSeller.getPrice()));
            ProductsEntities entity = ProductsEntities.getEntityByBestSeller(bestSeller);
            if(entity.getFavourite() == 0){
                favouriteIcon.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.ic_favorite_black_24dp);
            }else{
                favouriteIcon.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.favourite_icon);
            }
            favouriteIcon.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {
                if (isChecked) {
                    favouriteIcon.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.favourite_icon);
                    entity.setFavourite(1);
                    Repository.getRepository().addProductEntity(entity);
                    Toast.makeText(context, R.string.added_to_favourite, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    favouriteIcon.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.ic_favorite_black_24dp);
                    entity.setFavourite(0);
                    Repository.getRepository().addProductEntity(entity);
                    Toast.makeText(context, R.string.deleted_from_favourite, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the room database Dao :-

```
@Dao
public interface MercDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void addProduct(ProductsEntities entity);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM product_entity WHERE favourite_product == 1")
    LiveData<List<ProductsEntities>> getFavourites();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM product_entity WHERE cart_product == 1")
    LiveData<List<ProductsEntities>> getCart();

    @Query("UPDATE product_entity SET favourite_product = 1 WHERE product_id == :id")
    void setFavourite(String id);

    @Query("UPDATE product_entity SET cart_product = 1 WHERE product_id == :id")
    void setCart(String id);

    @Query("UPDATE product_entity SET cart_product = 0 WHERE product_id == :id")
    void deleteCart(String id);

    @Query("UPDATE product_entity SET favourite_product = 0 WHERE product_id == :id")
    void deleteFavourite(String id);
}
```

Here is my Room database entity :-

```
@Entity(tableName = "product_entity")
public class ProductsEntities {

    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "product_id")
    private String id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "product_name_en")
    private String nameEn;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "product_name_ar")
    private String nameAr;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "product_image")
    private String image;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "category_id")
    private String categoryId;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "store_id")
    private String storeId;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "product_price")
    private int price;
    // 1 for Recent ||  2 for BestSeller  ||  3 for CategoryProducts  ||  4 for StoreProducts
    @ColumnInfo(name = "product_type")
    private int product;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "favourite_product")
    private int favourite = 0;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "cart_product")
    private int cart = 0;

    public ProductsEntities() {

    }

    @NonNull
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(@NonNull String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNameEn() {
        return nameEn;
    }

    public void setNameEn(String nameEn) {
        this.nameEn = nameEn;
    }

    public String getNameAr() {
        return nameAr;
    }

    public void setNameAr(String nameAr) {
        this.nameAr = nameAr;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }

    public void setCategoryId(String categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }

    public String getStoreId() {
        return storeId;
    }

    public void setStoreId(String storeId) {
        this.storeId = storeId;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(int product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    public int getFavourite() {
        return favourite;
    }

    public int getCart() {
        return cart;
    }

    public void setFavourite(int favourite) {
        this.favourite = favourite;
    }

    public void setCart(int cart) {
        this.cart = cart;
    }
```

[click heart icon sends item to favorite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gem22.jpg)

[item in the favorite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEqmW.png)

[when refreshing the fragment icon back to normal again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzRLC.jpg)

[item still in the favorite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRB8f.png)

Comment: Whenever the user removes an item from the favourites, changes occur in the database and therefore the item in the recycler view must update. Therefore, you should whether the item is favourite or not in the `onBindViewHolder` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see 2 problems in the above code,

1. You are updating the Database when we add and remove that is fine, but how you are handling the local view reference is wrong.

   Reason: Because In your case, Not only if you go to another screen and come it will not work, if you scroll more if you have more item and come back also it will not work, Because of recycler view reuses your view which you updated in the check listener, This leads to the second issue
2. In onBindData you always should the non-fav icon, so whenever you scroll and view reuses it will show only non-fav icons, you should check whether the item is fav or not and you should update the view

For Example, you should do like below

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: VM, position: Int) {
    val item = items.get(position)

    if (item.favourite == 0) {
        holder.name.text = item.name
    } else {
        holder.name.text = item.name + " Liked "
    }

    holder.favouriteIcon.setOnCheckedChangeListener { compoundButton, isChecked ->
        // Should not update local view reference here
        if(isChecked) {
            // Update the local reference object, Just not to update from DB
            item.favourite = 1
            // Do the logic to update the DB to add the item in Fav
        } else {
            // Update the local reference object, Just not to update from DB
            item.favourite = 0
            // Do the logic to update to remove the item from Fav list
        }
        notifyItemChanged(position) // Helps to update the particular item
    }
}
```

Please modify the code based on your project.

Comment: i did what you say but nothing change i added check if the item is favorite or not and nothing change the item in the database but its icon still white should be red icon

Comment: Could you update the question with the latest code.